# PHP - 2D Arrays - Looping through array keys and retrieving their values?

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have an array that outputs like this:

```
1 => 
array
  'quantity' => string '2' (length=1)
  'total' => string '187.90' (length=6)

2 => 
array
  'quantity' => string '2' (length=1)
  'total' => string '2,349.90' (length=8)
```

I would like to loop through each array keys and retrieve the set of 3 values relating to them, something like this (which doesnt work):

```
foreach( $orderItems as $obj=>$quantity=>$total)
{
    echo $obj;
    echo $quantity;
    echo $total;
}
```

Would someone be able to give some advice on how I would accomplish this, or even a better way for me to be going about this task. Any information relating to this, including links to tutorials that may cover this, would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: Just a note, the "values" are not `1` and `2`; the KEYS are 1 and 2 - while the values associated with the keys 1 and 2 are the objects containing `quantity` and `total`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
foreach( $orderItems as $key => $obj)
{
    echo $key;
    echo $obj['quantity'];
    echo $obj['total'];
}
```

Using the above.

Comment: Thank you for your input, how would I obtain the key value tho? in my example it would be 1 and 2 respectively.

Answer (score 2):

You need to read the docs on `forEach()` a little more, since your syntax and understanding of it is somewhat incorrect.

```
$arr = array(
    array('foo' => 'bar', 'foo2', 'bar2'),
    array('foo' => 'bar', 'foo2', 'bar2'),
);
foreach($arr as $sub_array) {
    echo $sub_array['foo'];
    echo $sub_array['bar'];
}
```

`forEach()` iteratively passes each key of the array to a variable - in the above case, `$sub_array` (a suitable name, since your array contains sub-arrays). So within the loop body, it's that you need to interrogate.

Comment: Thanks for your input as it is very much appreciated. And yes you are correct about the docs too. But in my example I used `$obj` as well. Is it possible to retrieve this value? See the comment in the answer above please.

Comment: Well your `forEach` syntax is wrong so it's hard for me to use exactly what you put. It sounds like you want to use `$obj` instead of `$sub_array` as I have. I should have thought my example was quite easy to adapt to your purposes. If you expressly want me to edit to show this, let me know.